# adding hidden fields to accounts-entry sign-up page

Tags: meteor

The `accounts-entry` package let's you add custom fields through `extraSignUpFields` array. I am creating two different sign-up pages, I can dynamically change the `extraSignUpFields` array based on the page, but I don't know how to add a hidden field so I know in the database from what page a user has signed up.

Thanks

Comment: `extraSignUpFields: [{ name: location.pathname, type: "hidden",... }]` Not work for you?

Comment: @below9k thanks, that works, but i can't seem to set its value. without value a hidden field would be useless. can you guide me with that. the `name` attribute doesn't seem to be storing values when you have more than one fields.

Comment: After digging around the code, things don't look good. This package can't do what you want without modifications. `accounts-entry/client/views/signUp/extraSignUpFields.html line 10` add `value=name` to the `{{text_field ...}}` and I think that might work for you. Now every time you update it will break your new code, fyi. I bet this will work, but may cause some other fields to be populated you don't want.

Comment: No, it actually works in a magical way, the field key defines the field name and then after that you can assign the value by using that name without the quotes as the key, take a look:
`extraSignUpFields: [
          {
           field: "organization", organization: "xyz", label: "Organization", placeholder: "Amanullah Inc", type: "text", required: true
          },{
           field: "reg_type", reg_type: "provider", label: " ", placeholder: "ff", type: "hidden"
          }] `